# Fill 16:9 page with LaTeX in R-project

Tags: beamer, paper-size, rmarkdown

I'm programming a presentation based on different graphs inside R-project that use LaTeX to create pdf documents. 
I'm using LaTex with the beamer class and i would like to fill the page with the element that at the moment are in the center of the page without fill the A4 paper(16:9).

```
\documentclass[8pt, aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\paperwidth = 355pt
\paperheight = 255pt
```

and

```
include-before:
- \hoffset = 15pt 
- \voffset = 5pt 
- \oddsidemargin = -70pt 
- \headheight = 6pt 
- \headsep = -16pt 
- \textheight = 230pt 
- \textwidth = 320pt 
- \footskip = 8pt 
- \pagestyle{fancy} 
- \fancyhf{}
```

I tried to set `\documentclass[4paper, aspectratio=169]{beamer}`, to set `\setbeamersize` or `\geometry` but nothing working good, how can i fix it?

Comment: if yopu're using `beamer` all the stuff you list in `include-before` is wrong and shoudl not be used. The paperwidth/-height from the first sniplet should be removed as well.

Comment: So you're creating a document (presentation) using R-markdown? Can you add more detail so it's clear how you obtain your document?

Comment: If you're looking for freedom when positioning the elements on your page, just do `\hoffset = david`.

Comment: @daleif So if isn't correct include-before and paperwidth/-height how can i set the size? I tried with `\setbeamersize` but it doesen't work.
@Werner Yes, this is all i use for the set the size on my documents, it'w work so good the element are centred in the page but the size is small, if i you want to print more bigger i have to set right on the printer setting, but i want to have the documents just ready to print with the A4 page filled.
@thymaro What do you mean with `\hoffset = david`, by the way i just want to fill the A4 page.

Comment: IMO there is no need to set the actual size, just that the proportions are correct. All that extra code you're including is destroying what beamer is trying to do.

Comment: The 169 option sets the actual size of the canvas to be 16cm by 9cm.

Comment: @daleif ok but A4 size is 21.0 x 29.7cm, with `aspectratio=169` it should be 29.7cm x 21.0 and i want fill this size.

Comment: That is not a 16x9 ratio. See the beamer manual for a proper method for setting the canvas size.

Comment: @daleif If I knew how to do it I didn't write here :) I tried to set some parameters like `\setbeamersize` but nothing changed; In the beamer manual i read something like beamposter but i don't know ho to set it right.

Comment: It will never help setting say `\setbeamersize` if you still have those settings you present in your example. Beamer uses geometry minternally, so `\geometry{papersize={29.7cm,21cm}}` would be enough

Comment: @daleif ok thanks it's working good. I have one more question, there is a label that isn't fixed right now. How can i fix it? 
`# 3. Example
\label{section3}`

Comment: Please post another question and do include the geneated latex file, hardly any of us is using R to generate documents

Answer (score 1):

Minimal working example with a predetermined aspect ratio:

```
---
output: beamer_presentation
classoption: aspectratio=169  
---

Test
```

Another with a custom aspect ratio:

```
---
output: beamer_presentation
header-includes: \geometry{paperheight=1.5in,paperwidth=12in}
---

Test
```

Answer (score 0):

Putting classoption: "aspectratio=169" at the end of the header function properly in my case. The header follow below:

title: 'Title'
author: "Name"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
beamer_presentation:
highlight: pygments
theme: Madrid
colortheme: crane
fonttheme: professionalfonts
classoption: "aspectratio=169"